# How to get ASP.Net textbox values in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, api

On my ASP.Net/C# page, I have textboxes to enter in data for a transaction. I am using a payment API to accept credit card transactions. It comes with some sample code in jQuery, which I am editing (see below). The section of my code that says "data" is where I need help. I want to get the text from each asp.net textbox. My current idea below, such as `$(TxtAction).val()` does not actually pull the textbox value as I want. So I need some help on how I can get the text from the asp.net textboxes. I'd actually prefer to get the values in C# and then somehow send those values to my jQuery code or even just have everything in C# instead of jQuery. Any advice/help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    'Send a Credit Card Transaction'
    var settings = {
        "url": "URLHERE",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "X-Forte-Auth-Organization-Id": "IDHERE",
            "Authorization": "CODEHERE",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "data": "{\r\n    \"action\":" + $(TxtAction).val() + ",\r\n    \"authorization_amount\":" + $(TxtAuthorizationAmount).val() + ",\r\n   \"subtotal_amount\":" + $(TxtSubtotalAmount).val() + ",\r\n   \"billing_address\":{\r\n     \"first_name\":" + $(TxtFirstName).val() + ",\r\n     \"last_name\":" + $(TxtLastName).val() + ",\r\n  \"card\":{\r\n     \"card_type\":" + $(TxtCardType).val() + ",\r\n     \"name_on_card\":" + $(TxtCardName).val() + ",\r\n     \"account_number\":" + $(TxtCardNumber).val() + ",\r\n     \"expire_month\":" + $(TxtCardExpireMonth).val() + ",\r\n    \"expire_year\":" + $(TxtCardExpireYear).val() + ",\r\n     \"card_verification_value\":" + $(TxtCardVerificationCode).val() + ",\r\n  }\r\n}"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

})
```

Comment: `I'd actually prefer to get the values in C#` . no no! You really don't want to do that! But I think you are just missing a #.  `$("#TxtAction").val()`

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the textbox names to the jQuery selector `$(...)` without quotes, so it's interpreting those as variable names instead of selectors. Instead, you need to use `$('#TxtAction').val()` and so on.

Where "TxtAction" is the `id` attribute of each textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.  As Matt U said, you can fix your immediate problem by changing

```
$(TxtAction)
```

To:

```
$('#TxtAction').val()
```

That being said, I think you are making this a lot harder for yourself than you need to.  I wouldn't try and format your json in the JQuery. JQuery can do that for you!

```
"data": JSON.stringify({
    action: $('#TxtAction').val(),
    authorization_amount: $('#TxtSubtotalAmount').val(),
     ... and all the rest of your text box values ...
```

You can let jQuery do the messy work for you. `JSON.stringify({...})` will format your JSON string for you.

(Note: I've not tested this)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('[id$=TxtAction]').val()
```

instead of

```
$(TxtAction).val()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.